# How can I pass an objective-C object into a Kotlin Native framework?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

In particular, I need to zip a directory of files, and turn that into a single file.

```
// put all the log files in zipDirectory into a zip file named toFile
actual fun zip(zipDirectory: String, toFile: String)
```

I wasn't worried about this feature, because I had glibly assumed I could pass in an objective-c object into this object's constructor, and use it to run some cocoapods code... how wrong I was!

So now I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this task. Would love some ideas!

Comment: You have path to dir and path to output which are strings, so what obj-c object do you need to pass?

Comment: I would like to use a cocoapod that implements this feature, not "raw" native code (if Foundation already provides this feature by all means I'll use that!). So I was going to import the library in the project, wrap it in an @objc class, and pass that object in to the constructor of the above class, which would then call the zip() function inside that actual fun implementation.

Comment: Where I'm at now, though: create a new framework, import the cocoapod there, and make that framework available to the kotlin project via cinterop. I'm stuck on the build.gradle settings.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Using cocoapods plugin and importing cocoapod to your KMM module, so you can use it in your actual fun of iosMain, without needing to pass anything to the constructor. Check out about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/add-dependencies.html#with-cocoapods).

- pros: much less code
- cons: each pod added to KMM increases build time significantly, and as long as the cocoapods build caching is broken ([KT-43796](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43796)) I find it unusable.

2. Create an interface/abstract class for a "zipper", create constructor that take it, implement an instance of it on the iOS side and pass to the constructor.